# How to add new night-time/day-time variable depending on time range between two variables

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I wanted to add a new variable depending on the time range between two variables. I want times between 8:01-20:00 = day and times between 20:01-8:00 = night, and anything that overlaps both to be mixed.

I've tried to add the variable manually but trying to understand can this be done an easier way.

```
#Current database
id<-c("m1","m1","m1","m2","m2","m2","m3","m4","m4")
x<-c("2020-01-03 10:00:00","2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-05 10:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-06 06:30:00","2020-01-08 06:30:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00")
start<-strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
y<-c("2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-03 20:50:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-05 22:00:00","2020-01-06 07:40:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00","2020-01-08 08:55:00")
end<-strptime(y,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mydata<-data.frame(id,start,end)

#output
day.night<-c("day","day","mixed","day","mixed","night","night","night","mixed")
newdata<-cbind(mydata,day.night)
```

Edit: Apologies I forgot to add the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` is to convert `start.time` and `end.time` to `POSIXct` object and then compare the values at various intervals and apply labels using `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
   mutate(start.time1 = as.POSIXct(start.time, format = "%H:%M"), 
          end.time1 =  as.POSIXct(end.time, format = "%H:%M"), 
          day.night =  case_when(
          start.time1 > as.POSIXct('08:01:00', format = "%T") &
          end.time1 < as.POSIXct('20:00:00', format = "%T") ~"day",
          start.time1 > as.POSIXct('20:01:00', format = "%T") |
          start.time1 < as.POSIXct('08:00:00', format = "%T") & 
          end.time1 < as.POSIXct('08:00:00', format = "%T") ~ "night",
          TRUE ~ "mixed")) %>%
   select(names(data), day.night)

#  id start.time end.time day.night
#1 m1      10:00    16:00       day
#2 m1      16:00    19:20       day
#3 m1      19:20    20:50     mixed
#4 m2      10:00    15:20       day
#5 m2      15:20    20:50     mixed
#6 m2      20:50    22:00     night
#7 m3      06:30    07:40     night
#8 m4      06:30    07:50     night
#9 m4      07:50    08:55     mixed
```

**EDIT**

If we also have date one way would be to replace the date component in `start` and `end` with todays date for comparison purposes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydata %>%
   mutate_at(vars(start, end), ymd_hms) %>%
   mutate(start_hour = hour(start), 
          end_hour = hour(end), 
    day.night = case_when(start_hour >= 8 & end_hour >= 8 & end_hour < 20 ~ "day", 
                          start_hour >= 20 &  (end_hour < 8 | end_hour <= 23) |
                         (start_hour < 8 & end_hour < 8)~ "night", 
                           TRUE ~ "mixed"))

#    id               start                 end day.night
#1 m1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00       day
#2 m1 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00       day
#3 m1 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-03 20:50:00     mixed
#4 m2 2020-01-05 10:00:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00       day
#5 m2 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00     mixed
#6 m2 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 22:00:00     night
#7 m3 2020-01-06 06:30:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00     night
#8 m4 2020-01-08 06:30:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00     night
#9 m4 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00     mixed
```

Comment: Apologies I left out the date function

Comment: @Marcosullivan okay..updated the answer. See if it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, @ronak if the date crosses midnight this code does not work, i.e. if you change #3 end to 2020-01-04 00:50:00 you get "day" instead of "mixed".

Comment: @Sparky I have updated the answer in the **EDIT** part. Can you check now?

Comment: apologies @ronak any idea how to change "mixed" to where the majority of time was spent, i.e. in row 3, 40 minutes was spent in "day" and 50 minutes in "night" so this would become "night"?

Comment: @Sparky I would suggest you to ask a new question as this new request would require different approach altogether.